# How to append 2 different array in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have 1 empty array in react state for storing different images and videos. Like,

```
this.state = {
  imageArray: []
}
```

Now I am getting all the images and videos from my redux in an array. that array would be like,

```
fetchDataFromRedux:[{key:01_image, value: 'https://....},{key:02_image, value: 'https://....},{key:01_video, value: 'https://....}]
```

Now I want to append **fetchDataFromRedux** array into **this.state.imageArray**.

Currently, I am doing like this in **componentDidUpdate** while *prevProps* and *newProps* are not equal,

```
this.setState({imageArray: [...this.state.imageArray, ...fetchDataFromRedux]})
```

But whenever a new image or video added the length of the array would be double.

Comment: if `imageArray` is only used for display purpose, why can't use override the `imageArray` in the `ComponentDidUpdate` ?

Comment: Does `fetchDataFromRedux` always contains the updated data?

Comment: `this.setState(prev => ({imageArray: [...prev.imageArray, ...fetchDataFromRedux]}))`

Comment: @HassanImam Yes, fetchDataFromRedux always updated data.

Comment: @UrjitShah Then you can do `this.setState({imageArray:  [...fetchDataFromRedux]})` if `fetchDataFromRedux` always the updated one or you can use `fetchDataFromRedux` from the `props` itself, right?

Comment: Then why are you not reassigning your `imageArray` with it?

Comment: Remove `this.state.imageArray` from this.setState() you don't need that one.

Comment: @Thinker when I add a new image then I need old images as well as the newly added image that's why I used it in componentDidUpdate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does setting state with `prevState` value work as you intend?

```
this.setState((prevState) => {imageArray: [...prevState.imageArray, ...fetchDataFromRedux]})
```

Comment: That's great! Please mark it as the answer and upvote it if it was useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `Map` to remove the duplicates when you update the state in `componentDidUpdate`.

**Note:** I am removing the duplicates when updating the state in `componentDidMount`. You can do the same on `componentDidUpdate`

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Grid, Row, Col } from "react-flexbox-grid";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      imageArray: [
        {
          key: "01_image",
          value: "https://...."
        },
        {
          key: "02_image",
          value: "https://...."
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { imageArray } = this.state;

    const updatedArr = [
      {
        key: "02_image",
        value: "https://...."
      },
      {
        key: "03_image",
        value: "https://...."
      }
    ];

    const mergeArr = imageArray.concat(updatedArr);
    const mapArr = new Map(mergeArr.map((item) => [item.key, item]));
    this.setState({
      imageArray: [...mapArr.values()]
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { imageArray } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Row>
          {imageArray.map((item) => (
            <Col>{item.key}</Col>
          ))}
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Working Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-vxb0s?file=/index.js

Happy coding !!!

Comment: Yeah, it's working now and my issue is solved.

Thanks for helping!!! @Thinker

Happy coding

Comment: glad to help. If its working, can you approve the answer